# Como convertir de un tipo de dato, int a un float con 5 decimales en c++?

Tags: c++

¿Cómo convertir de un tipo de dato, `int` a un `float` con 5 decimales en C++?. Usando las librerías `<conio.h>` y `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que pretendes? un `int`, por definición, es entero y no tiene decimales. Mientras que un `float`, en cambio, no tiene limitado su número de decimales... aunque a partir del 7º decimal se consideran dígitos basura

Comment: Estimado, hace falta un resultado esperado y al menos un ejemplo de lo que haz intentado hacer. Por favor lee [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida.

Comment: Puedes convertirlo simplemente multiplicando por 1.0 y guardando el resultado en un float. Algo asi float aux = tuint * 1.0; Pero como dijo @eferion no puedes limitar el numero de decimales

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Cómo convertir de un tipo de dato, `int` a un `float` […]?

```
int dato = 42;
float conversion = dato;
```

Los tipos numéricos son convertibles entre si.

> ¿Cómo convertir de un tipo de dato, `int` a un `float` con 5 decimales en C++?

La cantidad de decimales que tiene un tipo flotante depende de su precisión, puede ir desde decenas a centenares de decimales.

Así que lo que entiendo que quieres no es *convertir* de entero a flotante con un número fijo de decimales si no *imprimir* un número en coma flotante usando un número fijo de decimales:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(5) << 42.00001f << '\n';
```

La línea anterior mostrará:

```
42.00001
```

> Usando las librerías `<conio.h>` y `<studio.h>`.

No necesitas la cabecera `<conio.h>` para imprimir ni convertir nada en C++ y la cabecera `<studio.h>` no existe.

Comment: La u no va, es `stdio.h`. Otra opción también es usar `printf()`

Comment: @Mateo Si se puede usar `printf` con c++ desaconsejalo, pues para usar la clase string a juro conocer su attributos y es muy engañoso: string hello_world="Hello world"; uno puede pensar que es un tipo de dato, pero no lo es realmente , es una clase. Al hacer: printf("%s",hello_world); me imagino que no dará el resultado que se espera pues no es un char[] y tambien existe la posibilidad que el attributo del string(char*) sea privado y por lo tanto no se tiene aceso a el o eso creo. En cambio la funcion cout está diseñada para tratar ese tipo de dato.